# Aligned equation in underbrace is too big

Tags: alignment, size, underbrace

Whenever you use underbrace in maths mode

```tex
\underbrace{x}_{=y}
```

y is in a smaller size than x.

But if I use an entire aligned equation

```tex
\underbrace{x}_{
   \begin{aligned}[t]
      &=y_1 \\
      &=y_2
   \end{aligned}
}
```

the aligned content is in normal size. This looks way too big. Is there a way to reduce the size again? `\scriptstyle` has no effect. `\scriptsize` does what I want, but it throws a warning that it is not supposed to be used in maths mode.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably mean

```
\underbrace{x}_{y}
```

You can get what you want with `subarray`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
\underbrace{x}_{\begin{subarray}{l} =y_1 \\ =y_2 \end{subarray}}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: can I use alignment `&` in subarrays?

Comment: @FelixB. No. But I can only answer what you ask for.